# Can we change a clearcase stream parent?

Tags: stream, clearcase

Can a child stream be reparented ?

eg

```
Int
 |-> StreamA 
       |-> StreamB
```

`StreamB` is child stream of `StreamA`, and `StreamA` is child stream of `Int` stream.
Will I be able to reparent `StreamB` to `Int`?

I want something like this

```
Int
 |-> StreamB
 |-> StreamA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

It is best to make another stream under Int, and then deliver directly from streamB to that new stream.

Remember that you can deliver from any stream to any other stream, as opposed to rebase, where you can only rebase from the direct parent stream.

Comment: Thanks, but Deliver operation cannot make sure that everything is exactly the same between StreamB and new stream right, there might be some merges that happen in a scenario where StreamB code is different than int stream.

Comment: @user2295704 true.I usually do the deliver, then, before completing said deliver, I check for differences, or even do a clearfsimport. Only then do I complete the deliver.